# Encoding problem vscode makes � appear instead of certain characters

Tags: php, html, mysql, visual-studio-code, character-encoding

I opened php files formerly developed on notepad++ with vscode and the special characters and with accents are not displayed with a �, how can I solve this problem. I am using UTF-8 encoding.

need help.

I have set "Files: Auto Guess Encoding" to yes but nothing change

Comment: that happens when you change from one characterset to another such as from ISO to UTF. By default VSC uses UTF-8. You need to change back to the original format or convert it.

Comment: Ok, how can i convert it ?

Comment: You need a file that isn't broken yet or you need to manually replace every broken character. If you have a non-broken file: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  Do you have the hex of some naughty text in the file?  The character causing the black diamond is not recoverable.